# Can a return type be const-qualified?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Consider:

```
typedef struct { int a[1]; } S;
const S foo(void) { return (S) {{3}}; }
void bar(void) { int *p = foo().a; }
```

Per C 2018 6.2.4 8, the expression `foo()` refers to an object with temporary lifetime:

> A non-lvalue expression with structure or union type, where the structure or union contains a member with array type (including, recursively, members of all contained structures and unions) refers to an object with automatic storage duration and *temporary lifetime*. Its lifetime begins when the expression is evaluated and its initial value is the value of the expression. Its lifetime ends when the evaluation of the containing full expression ends. Any attempt to modify an object with temporary lifetime results in undefined behavior. An object with temporary lifetime behaves as if it were declared with the type of its value for the purposes of effective type. Such an object need not have a unique address.

Note that the code does not attempt to modify the object, but it does initialize an `int *` with the address of the first element of `foo().a`, which we would expect to be `const`-qualified. This violates the constraints in 6.5.16.1 1 that require the pointed-to destination type to have all the qualifiers of the pointed-to source type. (That paragraph is for assignment but is incorporated by 6.7.9 11, which covers initialization.)

However, neither GCC nor Clang complain about this initialization. Indeed, with `-Wextra`, Clang complains about the return type of `foo`, saying “'const' type qualifier on return type has no effect”.

Are GCC and Clang wrong to treat `foo()` as not `const`-qualified? Or is there something in the C standard that says qualifiers on return types are disregarded?

(Lest one complain there is no use for this, consider one could have `baz(foo().a)`, in which the array is passed to a function which makes considerable use of it while it is a temporary object. However, if `baz` modified any part of the array, the behavior would not be defined by the C standard. A programmer might wish to forestall this error by declaring `foo`’s return type to be `const`, thus expecting to get a compiler error message if they accidentally pass an address in the temporary object to a function without a corresponding `const` in its parameter declaration.)

Comment: https://www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html#6.7.6.3p4, same as in c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf for function declaration of an `ident`: «the type specified for `ident` is “_derived-declarator-type-list_ function returning **the unqualified version of `T`**”», so `foo` has type `S(void)`

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Thanks, that should be an answer. It is paragraph 5 in the official C 2018 version.

Comment: Is this UB for a different reason (e.g. lifetime)? With `int *p = foo().a; baz(); printf("%d\n",*p);` has the call to `baz` destroyed the return value from `foo`? The usual is: `S copy = foo();` After that, the stack is popped to reclaim the temp area. But, does taking the address of `S.a` enough to preserve the implicit on stack copy?

Comment: @user3386109: This is a language-lawyer question, and the question being asked is at the top of the post. The bottom is not “the actual problem being considered” and was supplied only for motivation.

Comment: @user3386109: It does not take the address of an rvalue. As the passage I quoted from the C standard says, the expression `foo()` actually references an object, albeit one with temporary lifetime, and `foo().a` takes the address of a subobject of that object. This is defined and is in fact necessary, as, when accessing an element in an array inside a returned structure, as with `foo().a[0]`, the `[…]` operator has to operate on the address, so the usual automatic conversion of the array to a pointer to its first element occurs. This is why “temporary lifetime” was added to the standard.

Comment: @user3386109: And the code you say is valid, `baz(foo().a)`, also takes the address, as `foo().a` is automatically converted to the address of the first element of the array.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Interesting. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

§6.7.6.3p5 "Function declarators (including prototypes) > Semantics":

> If, in the declaration "**T D1**", **D1** has the form
>
> > **D** **(** *parameter-type-list* **)**
>
> or
>
> > **D** **(** *identifier-list*<sub>opt</sub> **)**
>
> and the type specified for *ident* in the declaration "**T D**" is "*derived-declarator-type-list T*", then the type specified for *ident* is "*derived-declarator-type-list* function returning the unqualified version of *T*"

So the type of `foo` is the same as if it was declared `S foo(void)`.

See also §6.7.3p5 "Type qualifiers > Semantics":

> The properties associated with qualified types are meaningful only for expressions that are lvalues.

So even if the first quoted paragraph didn't change the type, the const-qualification of the non-lvalue expression `foo()` would not be meaningful